# How do I load a local JSON file in a cordova app?

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

I have a question on how to load an local JSON file via an httpxmlRequest with pure JavaScript in a Cordova app.

I found out myself that it must have to do something with the file extension, since loading the file with an ".html" extension loads perfectly fine.

```
var filepath = "data/test.json";
var obj;
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
hr.open("POST", filepath, true);
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
hr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var res = hr.responseText;
        console.log("Response: " + res);
        obj = JSON.parse(res);
    }
};

// Send to server
hr.send("");
```

test.json:

```
{
  "price": 5,
  "time": "00:00"
}
```

test.html:

```
{
  "price": 5,
  "time": "00:00"
}
```

This code runs fine if the filepath ends with an file extension of ".html", but when changing it to ".json" it breaks and throws an 404 file not found error.

Comment: May we see the code you have so far (e.g. what worked with loading an HTML file)? It's a bit hard to work out what you have at the moment.

Comment: I edit my question and added the code part.

Comment: I guess it has to do something with the whitlisting.js plugin